# error showing on my practice "Unexpected character after atribute value"

Tags: javascript, html, character, html5-audio, articulate-storyline

New to using HTML and Javascript and trying to practice just placing text, buttons, etc. Getting "Unexpected Character After attribute value". What does this mean? i still am able to place everything so should i just ignore it? Thanks.

```
</head>
<body style="background: #FFFFFF" class="cs-HTML theme-classic">
  <!-- 360 -->
  <audio src=""id="bgSongku"preload="auto"autoplay loop></audio>
```

Comment: It means you have invalid syntax in your HTML after one of the `value` attributes. It should be `value=""`. Without knowing what your code looks like, I can't specifically point out where it's happening. You could paste your code into an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and it can show you.

Comment: Put spaces between the `name="value"` pairs, instead of writing them each directly after the other.